# Magnetic susceptibility

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, computational-physics

Currently I'm doing the simulation of Ising Model with Monte Carlo method. I got a curve which the magnetic susceptibility diverge (precisely due to finite size effect, it is not diverge but show the similar trend) when the temperature approach at critical temperature which is the point the model change from ferromagnetic state to paramagnetic state. This is what I expected as the second order phase transition, the second derivative on the free energy function is diverge. But I found so many graph which describe the magnetic susceptibility of material changing from ferromagnetic to paramagnetic got something like this[image]

Why there is such difference?

Comment: It may be a good idea to edit the title and change it to a *specific question* e.g. "Why don't many curves of X show Y behavior?"  Also, if you included one of your curves that can be compared to the example, that would show the difference better, which is important because your only question "Why there is such difference?" depends on a clear representation of that difference.